# Insertar html en MySQL con angular

Tags: php, mysql, angular

**EDITO**

Creo que el error viene de aquí

```
let json = JSON.stringify(homemodel);
```

Tengo un modelo en el cual en la propiedad

`home_settings.text_intro`
es de tipo **any** en ella tengo guardado texto con formato html.

Si inserto por ejemplo `<p>Hola</p>` lo inserta sin problema, pero sin embargo si inserto una tabla no me inserta, directamente me llega vacío a mi API en PHP.

El campo de la base de datos es VARCHAR y para hacer el update del campo hago lo siguiente:

```
    updateTexthome() {
    console.log(this.home_settings.text_intro);
    this._route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
      this.Homeservice.updateTexthome(this.home_settings.id, this.home_settings).subscribe(
        result => {
          if(result['code'] == 200) {
            console.log('Home actualizada con éxito');
            this.getHomeSettings();
          } 
          else {
            console.log('Home no actualizada con éxito');
          }
        },
        error => {
          console.log('Ha sucedido un error');
          console.log(<any>error);
        }
      );
    });
  }
```

Este es mi service

```
  updateTexthome(id, homemodel: HomeModel) {
    let json = JSON.stringify(homemodel);
    let params = 'json='+json;
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});
    return this.Http.post(this.url+'/home-text/'+id, params,{headers})
  }
```

Y esta sería mi API en PHP

```
    $app->post('/home-text/:id', function ($id) use($db, $app) {

    $json = $app->request->post('json');
    $data = json_decode($json, true);

    var_dump($data['text_intro']);

    $query = "UPDATE home SET ". "text_intro = '{$data['text_intro']}' WHERE id = '{$id}';";

    $insert = $db->query($query);
    $result = array(
        'status'  => 'error',
        'code'    => 404,
        'message' => 'Fallo al actualizar home',
    );

    if ($insert) {
        $result = array(
            'status'  => 'success',
            'code'    => 200,
            'message' => 'Home no actualizada correctamente',
        );
    }

    echo json_encode($result);
 });
```

Comment: No entendí mucho cuál es el problema. ¿Depuraste los datos cuando mandas una tabla?

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta :/ los mando tal y como está en el código

Comment: Me refiero a que si has depurado con un `console.log(home_settings.text_intro);` y en PHP con `var_dump` para ver realmente qué salida se está produciendo.

Comment: Sí, al php no me llega el html haciendo un var_dump... :/ es problema de angular me temo

Comment: Pues depura en Angular para verificar qué datos se están enviando. Aprender a depurar adecuadamente te va a ahorrar horas y horas de comedera de coco buscando el problema. Cuando trabajas con datos no debes *imaginar* que las cosas son como crees, sino que debes **verificar** que realmente las cosas son así y eso se hace depurando los datos en sí mismos.

Answer (score 1):

Un problema que veo esta dentro del servicio updateTexthome en la variable params. Yo intentaría con:

```
const params = { json: homemodel }
```

sin el JSON.stringify

Y en el header dejar 
'Content-Type':  'application/json'

De otro modo en lugar de JSON.stringify intentaría replicar la serialización que por ejemplo hace JQuery

[jQuery.param()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/)

En Angular esto se puede hacer con el método toString de [HttpParams](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams#toString)

Comment: Hola no entiendo que quiere decir, en el servicio quito el let params y reempleazo con const params... ?

Answer (score 1):

Mandar puedes mandarlo perfectamente con json stringify , de hecho yo lo hago en varios proyecto, aunque el back esta en nestjs pero vamos igual, yo creo que lo que podrías hacer es quitar los headers, y antes de mandar al backend realizar un console.log() del json que quieres enviar para ver que todo esta correcto y luego lo mismo en la parte del backend, depurar que es lo que te viene, porque seguro que algo o no se manda correcto o no se recibe correcto, o bien el campo de la base de datos es un varchar en el que no cabe el json y te peta la base de datos.
En el servicio

```
  updateTexthome(id, homemodel: HomeModel) {
let json = JSON.stringify(homemodel);
let params = 'json='+json;
console.log(params)
return this.Http.post(this.url+'/home-text/'+id, params)
}
```

y en el back

```
$app->post('/home-text/:id', function ($id) use($db, $app) {
var_dump($app);
$json = $app->request->post('json');
$data = json_decode($json, true);

var_dump($data['text_intro']);

$query = "UPDATE home SET ". "text_intro = '{$data['text_intro']}' WHERE id = '{$id}';";

$insert = $db->query($query);
$result = array(
    'status'  => 'error',
    'code'    => 404,
    'message' => 'Fallo al actualizar home',
);

if ($insert) {
    $result = array(
        'status'  => 'success',
        'code'    => 200,
        'message' => 'Home no actualizada correctamente',
    );
}

echo json_encode($result); });
```

Comment: El campo de la DB lo cambié a TEXT para asegurarme que cabe el json, llego a casa y pruebo a ver

Comment: @MiguelÁngelMartín que tal fue?

Comment: El console.log de params, me muestra el html ''<figure class=\"table\"><table><tbody><tr><td>&nbsp;</td><'' pero no se llega a insertar...